# Sublime Text 2 - BeautifyRuby don't work

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, package-control, beautify-ruby

i've installed BeautifyRuby in my Sublime Text 2 (running OS X Yosemite 10.10), but is not working, I receive this message when I try to cmd + ctrl + k:

> Error: invalid output. Check your ruby interpreter settings

I've changed, as suggested https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby , the sublime-settings file with:

```
"ruby": "/Users/alessiogastaldo/.rbenv/bin/ruby"
```

and also using the specific version:

```
"ruby": "/Users/alessiogastaldo/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby"
```

but with no success.

I've read the different solutions proposed (like https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby/issues/52) but nothing works.

Anyone do know how to solve this?

Comment: "but is not working" it's a little bit vague. What is the issue? Please clarify your question with a specific problem or error.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti you are right, sorry. Erorr message added

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too.
I solved with this:

1. In terminal, run the command: `which ruby`.
2. Copy the result. In my case was: `"/home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby"`
3. Open your package settings. In my case: `Preferences > Package Settings > BeautyfyRuby > Settings Default`.
4. Add this line in the file: `"ruby": "/home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby",`

You will need to install the `htmlbeautifier gem`.

5. Run the commmand in terminal: `gem install htmlbeautifier`

It works for me.